# Anyone know the LG Ally screen density?

Tags: screen

I'm doing some android development and one of the specific devices I need to test on is the LG ally. The [tech specs on their web site](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=http://www.lg.com/us/mobile-phones/LG-VS740.jsp&ei=VNuDTfGALYbYgQfxyOHfCA&usg=AFQjCNEn1Mb193k8h74Nktpjq7OJSPWtoQ&sig2=wP__6Rsgb5nYYLyRZ75t2A) list the display resolution as 480 x 800, but I also need the density in order to emulate the screen properly (the difference between 160 and 240 dpi is huge).

Anyone know the screen density for the LG Ally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about 290 DPI (just crunch the numbers: Use the pythagorean equation to get the "pixels" diagonally, then divide by the screen diagonal).

Comment: No problem.  It's easier if you have the screen width/height (then you can just divide the pixels wide by the width, or the px high by the height) but those measurements are harder to come by.